# Pagination includes _token string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm adding pagination to my view but for some reason the URL string includes a "_token" string. How can I remove that?

Here is How my controller looks like:

```
public function index($client_id, Request $request)
    {
        $client = Client::where('id', $client_id)->first();

        if ($request->search) {
            $extensions = Extension::query()
                ->where('first_name', 'like', '%'. $request->search .'%')
                ->where('client_id', 'like', '%'. $client_id .'%')
                ->paginate(5);
        }else{
            $extensions = Extension::where('client_id', $client_id)->paginate(5)->withQueryString();
        }

        return view("pages.extensions.index", compact('client', 'extensions'));

    }
```

My index blade has this:

```
<!-- Top Bar -->
<div>
        <form action="{{ route('extensions.index', [$client->id]) }}" method="GET">
         @csrf
          <x-input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by First Name..." />
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
</div>
                            
<!-- Table -->

// A table goes here

<!-- Pagination Link -->
<div>
{{ $extensions->links() }}
</div>
```

Here is how looks like the URL after I use the search:
`http://127.0.0.1:8001/clients/1/extensions?_token=Cdri3a6GEEOe90I9niEmVI&search=frodo`

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `@csrf` from your form.

As your form is doing GET request the `_token` is not needed at all.

Comment: That removed the token from the  URL. Thank you.